# Status check of service is failing

Tags: service, command-line, vbscript, wmi, windows-server-2008-r2

I am working on Windows 2008 Server R2. I found this VBScript that should be checking the whether a service is either started or stopped.

Here is the script:

```
'Declare Variables
Dim objWMIService, objProcess, colProcess, Status, strComputer, strService

'Assign Arguments
strComputer = WScript.Arguments(0)
strService = WScript.Arguments(1) 
Status = False

'Check For Arguments - Quit If None Found
If Len(strService) < 1 Then
    Wscript.echo "No Arguments Entered - Exiting Script"
    WScript.Quit
End If

'Setup WMI Objects
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:"& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("SELECT DisplayName, Status, State FROM Win32_Service WHERE DisplayName = '" & strService & "'")

'Check For Running Service
For Each objProcess In colProcess
    If InStr(objProcess.DisplayName, strService) > 0 And objProcess.State = "Running" Then
        Status = True
    End If
Next

If Status = True Then
    WScript.Echo "Service: " & UCase(strComputer) & " " & strService & " Running"
Else
    WScript.Echo "Service: " & UCase(strComputer) & " " & strService & " Not Running"
End If
```

Via the command line I call the script like this

```
CSCRIPT ServiceCheckScript.vbs LOCALHOST "Print Spooler"
```

Response from the command line is

> ...\ServiceCheckScript.vbs(20, 1) (null): 0x80041017

I see that the 0x80041017 error refers to result of a query returning a null value, but I am not sure as to why that may be.

Comment: On my Windows 7 machine it works fine. For some reason that error code is reminding me of the error code that is returned when WMI is broken. Try this: start > run > wbemtest (open it) > Connect > Connect > Query > [type] `select * from win32_service` > Apply. If at any point you get an error (including when clicking Connect, excluding if you make a typo in the query) then your WMI is broken.

Comment: Error 0x8041017 indicates that your [query is invalid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394559.aspx). Double check that the value of `strService` is what you expect it to be (e.g. with a statement like `WScript.Echo "-" & strService & "-"`).

Comment: Doesn't WMI use `.` to denote the current machine rather then `localhost`? Guess it should still work, just an observation.

Comment: @Lankymart The moniker allows `.`, `localhost`, IP address or hostname. Also, a problem with the moniker string should raise a different error (at an earlier point, too).

Answer (score 0):

A few issues with the above code:

1. Verify you got results from your WMI query so you don't attempt to use a null.  Wrap the use of the results in `if colProcess.count > 0 then`.
2. Remove the extra .quit by enclosing your code in the parameters verification.  Its cheaper/cleaner to do this with an argument count than a string function `wscript.arguments.count = 2` since you were only checking to ensure they were not empty.  If you need a more sophisticated validation, then more logic would be required.
3. There isn't any reason to use `instr(objProcess.Displayname, strService)` because your WMI query already specified that the results are equal to the service display name in this, `where DisplayName = strService`.
4. It's simpler/clearer to perform the conditional inspection of service status all inside the loop.

Here is my example.

```
'Declare Variables
Dim objWMIService, objProcess, colProcess, Status, strComputer, strService

'Verify arguments were passed
if WScript.Arguments.Count = 2 then
   'Assign Arguments
   strComputer = WScript.Arguments(0)
   strService = WScript.Arguments(1) 

   'Setup WMI Objects
   Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:"& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
                       strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
   Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("SELECT DisplayName, Status, State FROM " & _
                    "Win32_Service WHERE DisplayName = '" & strService & "'")

   'Ensure there were results returned
   if colProcess.count > 0 then
      'Check For Running Service
      For Each objProcess In colProcess
         If objProcess.State = "Running" Then
            WScript.Echo "Service: " & UCase(strComputer) & " " & strService & " Running"
         else
            WScript.Echo "Service: " & UCase(strComputer) & " " & strService & " Not Running"
         End If
      Next
   else
      WScript.Echo "Service: " & UCase(strComputer) & " " & strService & " Does not exist"
   end if
end if
```

edit:  Just adding that I validated the above code in both Win 8.1 and Server 2012R2, using both valid and invalid service names.  However, I would add more error checking, like verifying the computer parameter is valid to ensure your WMI query doesn't fail unnecessarily/inexplicably.